# Deployment Hell: Sinatra and Datamapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, runtime-error, datamapper, shared-hosting

I'm having one heck of a hard time getting my really simple Sinatra/Datamapper app up and running on Bluehost (shared hosting).

It runs perfectly on localhost.

I actually got it working before the database was implemented, but now that it is I am going nuts trying to figure out what is wrong.

Starting the database

```
    DataMapper.setup(:default,"sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/prod.db")
```

EDIT: Ok I found out that this should be

```
    DataMapper.setup(:default,"sqlite:#{Dir.pwd}/prod.db")
```

At the end of the models,

```
    DataMapper.finalize.auto_migrate!
```

Now, I've tried to fiddle around with the setup ("sqlite::memory:") and other stuff but I either get the undecypherable "Application error
Ruby application failed to start properly"

or some other stuff.

I know I'm not very specific, but what I'm asking is are there any common pitfalls about deploying Sinatra + Datamapper apps on a shared hosting (Bluehost)?

For instance before this I had to change alle the 'require_relative' to 'require 'full_path.rb''

Anybody knows of some common issues? I'm seriously starting to lose it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it.
    DataMapper.setup(:default,"sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/prod.db")

should be (contrary to what the docs say)

```
DataMapper.setup(:default,"sqlite:#{Dir.pwd}/prod.db")
```

and all this should end with

```
DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
```

not 'auto_migrate!'